# How to create a slice of variable type in Go?

Tags: go, reflection

I have a function.

```
func doSome(v interface{}) {

}
```

If I pass by pointer a slice of struct into the function, the function must fill the slice.

```
type Color struct {
}
type Brush struct {
}

var c []Color
doSome(&c) // after с is array contains 3 elements type Color

var b []Brush
doSome(&b) // after b is array contains 3 elements type Brush
```

Maybe I need use reflection, but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
func doSome(v interface{}) {

    s := reflect.TypeOf(v).Elem()
    slice := reflect.MakeSlice(s, 3, 3)
    reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem().Set(slice)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

typeswitch!!

```
package main
import "fmt"

func doSome(v interface{}) {
  switch v := v.(type) {
  case *[]Color:
    *v = []Color{Color{0}, Color{128}, Color{255}}
  case *[]Brush:
    *v = []Brush{Brush{true}, Brush{true}, Brush{false}}
  default:
    panic("unsupported doSome input")
  }
}  

type Color struct {
    r uint8
}
type Brush struct {
    round bool
}

func main(){
    var c []Color
    doSome(&c) // after с is array contains 3 elements type Color

    var b []Brush
    doSome(&b) // after b is array contains 3 elements type Brush

    fmt.Println(b)
    fmt.Println(c)

}
```

Comment: No! :) Its bad practice. if i add new type, function doSome() need modify.

Comment: I think it's *good* practice because it forces you to code `doSome()` explicitly instead of taking a guess at the behavior. If you want doSome to always create EMPTY slices then you could use `b := make([]Brush, 3)` instead of `doSome(&b)`

Answer (score 1):

Go has no generics. Your possibilities are:

Interface dispatching

```
type CanTraverse interface {
    Get(int) interface{}
    Len() int
}
type Colours []Colour

func (c Colours) Get(i int) interface{} {
    return c[i]
}
func (c Colours) Len() int {
    return len(c)
}
func doSome(v CanTraverse) {
    for i := 0; i < v.Len; i++ {
        fmt.Println(v.Get(i))
    }
}
```

Type switch as @Plato suggested

```
func doSome(v interface{}) {
  switch v := v.(type) {
  case *[]Colour:
    //Do something with colours
  case *[]Brush:
    //Do something with brushes
  default:
    panic("unsupported doSome input")
  }
}
```

Reflection as fmt.Println() do. Reflection is very powerful but very expensive, code may be slow. Minimal example

```
func doSome(v interface{}) {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    if value.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        for i := 0; i < value.Len(); i++ {
            element := value.Slice(i, i+1)
            fmt.Println(element)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("It's not a slice")
    }
}
```